# Batch mode images on white background of A5 size

Tags: linux, image-processing, terminal

I have about 260 scanned images of text that I ‘tailored’ with `scantailor` so that they are cropped to contain only text area (no margins on any side). They are all a bit smaller than the size of A5 (the hard copy is A5).

Now, what I want is to put all of them (individually) on white background of A5 size, horizontally centred, vertically the image should start 0.88 inches from the top of the background. All should be done in terminal in batch mode. Probably the imagemagick should do this job, but I cannot imagine how.

Info: Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 i386

**Update #1**

`convert bg.tif fg.tif -gravity center -composite new.tif`

This command is partially suficient, but it centres the `fg.tif` horizontally **and** vertically. But I have no idea how to put the `fg.tif` 0.88 inches from top while horizontally centred.

Btw, all images are 300 dpi. In this update #1, the `bg.tif` is an image created in gimp that is of A5 size and has white background and processed with all the same settings in scantailor to get the same image qualities as the other files.

**Undate #2**

I have just manually found out the the following command puts the fg image approx .88 inches from top:

`composite -geometry +0+264 fg.tif blnk_300.tif new.tif`

but to combine it with `-gravity center` is not that simple, for the next command first centres it (horiz **and** vert) and than adds `+0+264`:

`composite -gravity center -geometry +0+264 130b.tif blnk_300.tif new.tif`

so that the output is somewhat doubled from top (that is +0+528) while horizontally still centred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step I have not been yet able to accomplish from terminal, so I opened gimp,

1. created new image (**ctrl+n**),
2. template: **A5 (300 ppi)**
3. after clicking on Advanced options, fill with: **White**
4. click on ok (or press enter)

Then exported (ctrl+e) it to bg.tif (when asked, select **No compression** and export/enter). For it had about 13 MB, I decided to scantailor it (the way as other scanned images to have the same qualities).

And finally, the command:

`composite -gravity center -gravity north -geometry +0+264 130b.tif blnk_300.tif new.tif`

I just tried to use multiple `-gravity` settings and it just worked!